# Handle random keys with kotlinx serialization

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

I am trying to serialize the content of a json string that can take the following format:

```
  -723232569: {
    "lat": 8.2,
    "lon": -90.3,
    "schedule": {
      "friday": [
        {
          "date_arr": "friday",
          "remarks": " OK",
          "time_arr": "07:10",
          "time_dep": "06:40",
          "trans_name": "C"
        }
      ]
    }
```

However I am struggling with my current serializable class implementation. The top key (-723232569) will vary, it will be generated randomly from one iteration to another. I would like to extract they key and its value with the following class implementation.

```
@Serializable
data class TimeSlot(val date_arr: String,
                    val remarks: String,
                    val time_arr: String,
                    val time_dep: String,
                    val trans_link: String,
                    val trans_name: String,
                    val trans_tel: String,
                    val to_lat: String? = null,
                    val to_lon: String? = null)

@Serializable
data class Schedule(val monday: List<TimeSlot>,
                    val tuesday: List<TimeSlot>,
                    val wednesday: List<TimeSlot>,
                    val thursday: List<TimeSlot>,
                    val friday: List<TimeSlot>,
                    val saturday: List<TimeSlot>,
                    val sunday: List<TimeSlot>)
@Serializable
data class Stop(val lat: Double,
                val lon: Double,
                val schedule: Schedule)
```

However when executing the following code I am encountering

```
    try {
    val neww = """-723232569: {
    "lat": 8.2,
    "lon": -90.3,
    "schedule": {
      "friday": [
        {
          "date_arr": "friday",
          "remarks": " OK",
          "time_arr": "07:10",
          "time_dep": "06:40",
          "trans_name": "C"
        }
      ]
    }"""


       val res = format.decodeFromString<Stop>(neww)
        } catch (ioException: IOException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace()
        }
```

> ```
> Unexpected JSON token at offset 27: Encountered an unknown key '-723232569'.
>     Use 'ignoreUnknownKeys = true' in 'Json {}' builder to ignore unknown keys.
> ```